# In homebrewing a subclass on D&D Beyond, how do I add a feature that does extra damage based on an ability score modifier?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, dnd-beyond

I'm adding a version of the UA Phoenix Soul sorcerer to my homebrew stuff, and I'm a little perplexed when it comes to adding damage for Mantle of Flame.

The relevant text of the feature reads:

> Any creature takes fire damage equal to your Charisma modifier if it hits you with a melee attack from within 5 feet of you or if it touches you.
>
> Whenever you roll fire damage on your turn, the roll gains a bonus equal to your Charisma modifier.

In trying to add both of these features, if I select Modifier Type "Damage," then there doesn't seem to be an option to add a character's Charisma modifier. If I select Modifier Type "Bonus," there's a Charisma modifier option, but there doesn't seem to be a way to indicate it's damage.

How do I proceed?

This is probably all very obvious and I'm missing something right in front of my face, but I'd love some guidance.

Comment: Have you looked in the DnD Beyond forums? There's quite a lot of info there and it's quite a good place to post specific questions like this.

Comment: Good suggestion. I searched them to see whether anybody had asked this question already, and I couldn't find anything, but I didn't think to ask it there as well. I'll go do that now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There probably isn't a good way

I'm definitely not an expert on D&D Beyond's homebrew creation system, but by comparing to the closest working option I could find hasn't provided a working option.

The Bracers of Archery provide a +2 to damage from Shortbows (among other benefits). This is automatically added to the damage roll right on the character sheet:
[image: Shortbow with Bracers of Archery shows 1d6+2]

The Modifier for the damage bonus looks like this:
[image: Selected values are Damage Shortbow 2]

If we remove the "Fixed Value: 2" and add "Ability Score: CHA" like so:
[image: Selected values are Damage Shortbow CHA]

Then the Shortbow damage receives a bonus equal to the Charisma modifier, which is good other than being a Shortbow:
[image: Shortbow with modified item shows 1d6+CHA]

Going back to the item, we can change the subtype from "Shortbow" to "Fire":
[image: Selected values are Damage Fire CHA]

However, when we look at the character equipped with the newest custom item Fire Bolt has not received the damage bonus:
[image: Fire Bolt with modified item shows normal damage]

There isn't any other Subtype that seems remotely applicable, so this method sadly does not work for your purposes.

If they add the functionality later, it might be done as a Subtype of a "Bonus" modifier, which seems to be how the Cleric's Knowledge Domain subclass and the Warlock's Agonizing Blast invocation are implemented, but no appropriate option is currently available:
[image: Cleric Cantrip Damage and Eldritch Blast Damage are listed as subtypes of Bonus]

You can manually adjust individual spells to give them the bonus damage if you want, but from my tinkering there isn't a way to make that bonus adjust with Charisma changes, or a way to have that adjustment applied based on the damage type, so it's probably more convenient to just keep track of it yourself.

For the other feature I don't think there's really anything for D&D Beyond to even do. There isn't a roll required or any D&D Beyond feature for determining what things activate when you are hit with an attack, so it will be up to you to track it regardless.

Comment: Wow—thank you for such a thorough and helpful (if slightly disappointing) answer! I really appreciate the time and energy you put into this.